# Sort multiple lines based on one line

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, line, recursive-query

I've a file with following lines:

```
Name: Karl
Born: 2003-07-06 17:21:36.964
State: Germany
Hobby: Videogames

Name: Albert
Born: 2003-07-05 18:16:19.369
State: UK
Hobby: Soccer

Name: Mark
Born: 2003-06-15 16:58:21.201
State: Italy
Hobby: Jogging
```

I need a shell script that orders from the older to the younger the lines between the blank lines based on the Born field. Based on the example given the right file result should be:

```
Name: Mark
Born: 2003-06-15 16:58:21.201
State: Italy
Hobby: Jogging

Name: Albert
Born: 2003-07-05 18:16:19.369
State: UK
Hobby: Soccer

Name: Karl
Born: 2003-07-06 17:21:36.964
State: Germany
Hobby: Videogames
```

I'm unable to do such thing, please no perl or python... I need bash.
Ty all in advance for your help.
Regards,
Dave

Comment: Welcome. As SO is not a free coding service, you are expected to try something first, come back here with your own code, explain what issues you encounter with it and ask for help with **your** code. By the way, is it `bash` only or could `awk` be an option? If `awk` is an option you could search a bit about the effect of an [empty record separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line) (`RS`) and this would probably be a good staring point.

Comment: bash (or any other shell) would be a terrible choice for this - lengthy, complicated, slow, fragile, non-portable, etc. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Use awk or some other text processing tool instead, this is not what shells are designed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you alread have some answers, may as well throw out another one... using GNU awk for [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '
    { recs[$2] = ( $2 in recs ? recs[$2] ORS : "" ) $0 } 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (i in recs) {
            print recs[i]
        }
    }
' file
Name: Mark
Born: 2003-06-15 16:58:21.201
State: Italy
Hobby: Jogging

Name: Albert
Born: 2003-07-05 18:16:19.369
State: UK
Hobby: Soccer

Name: Karl
Born: 2003-07-06 17:21:36.964
State: Germany
Hobby: Videogames
```

See [Multiple-Line Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line) for what those `RS`, `ORS`, and `FS` (`-F`) settings do.

The above reads all of your input into memory before printing it and preserves the relative input order of records that have the same timestamp as each other.

Comment: if you set FS to `\n` and indexed by the full timestamp (`$2`) wouldn't you get a total ordering instead of partial?

Comment: This solution is brillant, but if I've undestood the logic it works for the example, but trying to apply it i noticed that some Name: have just "Mark", others have "Mark Jr", so the sort for those doesn't work. But I must admit that I've learned something new. Ty very much

Comment: @RenaudPacalet good point, I updated that.

Comment: @jhnc yeah, I've done that now, thanks.

Comment: @DaveDolone it's important that the sample data you provide in your question look like your real data. If your real data doesn't always have single word names then don't only include single word names in your example or we can't test a potential solution with it, as in this case. I've updated my answer to hopefully work for that case plus the timestamp issue that Renauld and jhnc pointed out but please edit your question to fix your example so it correctly demonstrates your requirements and we can test a potential solution using it.

Comment: I've worked on your solution and I solved my issue. Ty very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapfile -d '' data <file

data=${data//$'\r'}
data=${data//$'\n'/$'\r'}
data=${data//$'\r\r'/$'\r\n'}

printf '%s' "$data" |
sort -t$'\r' -k2,2 |
tr '\r' '\n'
```

- load data
- convert records into single lines
- sort
- convert back to multiple lines

---

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { r[NR]=$0; next }
    { print s r[$1]; s="\n" }
' RS= file RS="\n" <(
    grep ^Born: file |
    cat -n | 
    sort -k3
)
```

- extract dates, tag with record number, sort
- load records into awk
- load sorted dates, extract tag, print record

Comment: I tried your solution but on RH i get following error:
bash: mapfile: -d: invalid option
mapfile: usage: mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]

Comment: what's output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` ?

Comment: `-d` option was added in bash 4.4

Answer (score -1):

You're breaking the rules trying to get free coding done. Also Unix shell is not particularly good at this kind of thing, and if there's any way you can obtain the data in a different format, like json (for which there are great tools available) you should do that. But I'll give you a free tip on what might work:

```
while read NAME
do
read BORN
read STATE
read HOBBY
read
echo "$NAME@$BORN@$STATE@$HOBBY" 
done < mydata.txt | sort -r -t@ -k2,2 | (
IFS=@
while read NAME BORN STATE HOBBY
do
echo $NAME
echo $BORN
echo $STATE
echo $HOBBY
echo
done
)
```

I haven't tested it, but it gives you an idea.

Comment: That would be extremely slow and fail in various ways given various input values and/or environment settings. If you copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the issues but then see also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: @EdMorton It's a bizarre theory that because bash has reserved variables, therefore you shouldn't use uppercase variables. All sorts of things are going to reserve names. Like lots of things assume what JAVA_HOME is or ORACLE_HOME ... they happen to be upper case, but let's say they were lower case, and you happened to stamp on them and break stuff... then you broke stuff... So bash isn't unique in reserving variables you shouldn't touch, so it doesn't deserve special treatment. C++ reserves while and if. Does that mean I shouldn't use lower case variables in C++? Of course not.

Comment: @EdMorton As for shell loops to process text being bad practice I JUST SAID THAT. But the OP asked for it, so I gave him what he wanted.

Comment: Nothing bizarre about it, I frequently see shell scripts where USER, HOME, PATH, etc., etc. are being used as local variables and so causing breakage. Shell reserves `while` and `if` too but, just like C++, that's not a problem because if you try to use one as a variable you'll almost certainly get a syntax error rather than your code quietly and mysteriously behaving undesirably as it would if you did `for PATH in ...`. In C++ you hopefully have a convention to use all upper case for #defined symbols and not to use all upper case for variable names to avoid clashes and make code readable.

Comment: "Don't use all upper case for non-exported variables" is up there with "quote your variables unless you NEED to not quote them" as absolute fundamentals of shell programming that cause so many problems for newcomers when they don't understand those rules. As for shell loops to process text being bad practice - where exactly did you say that? You didnt say it in your answer or any comments that I can see. Giving the OP slow, buggy code, even if they asked for it in some sense, without an explanation of the issues around it isnt helping them or anyone else who reads this in future.

Comment: I said "Unix shell is not particularly good at this kind of thing", do I need to use your exact words to not get lambasted? It's not true that newcomers frequently have problems with upper case  variables. The idea that environment variables are upper case is not a convention that the shell itself follows, so if you learn that rule, you're already wrong before you start. You also don't know what variables are environment variables. If I declare in my script ": ${foo:=bar}", is that an environment variable? At runtime, you don't know.